# Better than linear: how to train multiple ML models?

Tags: python, serialization, machine-learning, configuration, parallel-processing

For ML tasks, I typically want to compare several models. The pseudo-code can be like this:

```
preprocesssing
for model in models:
    model.fit(X_train,y_train)
postprocessing and evaluation
```

I was wondering if there is any (python) framework that would improve this functionality by:

1. Parallelization of model training
2. Serialization of models once each is trained
3. Showing the intermediate results
4. Specification of the models e.g. by XML or other similar model

I have found a related question here: [Train multiple different sklearn models in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47980936/train-multiple-different-sklearn-models-in-parallel) , but it does not answer my question fully. I am quite convinced that there must be already a framework for that.

Answer (score 0):

First,
for some principal disambiguations
between
a pure-**`[SERIAL]`**,
a "just"-**`[CONCURRENT]`** and
a true-**`[PARALLEL]`**, **[kindly review remarks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49341944/3666197)**  in your derrogated post

---

### Next on topic:

---

**1 ) TRAINING :**
Different ML-models ( principally ), but also the same model ( having adjacent hyper-parameter settings ), do **`.fit()`** in different run-time durations, so a true-**`[PARALLEL]`** schedule is principally not achievable, a "just"-**`[CONCURRENT]`** processing comes feasible in many ML-pipeline automation tools. Besides the initial view, you may be also aware, that the Python GIL-stepped issues are in common being escaped from, by going **`multiprocessing`** and/or into a [distributed-system](/questions/tagged/distributed-system) architecture, right because of the performance issues.

**2 ) SERIALISATION :**
One may remind, that except some uniquely "friendly" exceptions, all the generic SER/DES operations are pure-[SERIAL] by nature, in the "mild" area of the **`O( N )`** domain of the Complexity-ZOO.

**3 ) DISPLAYING PROGRESS :**
A non-core part of the professional / HPC ML-pipelines, yet if willing to pay **`[TIME]`**-domain costs for a few such pieces of information, better report indirectly into some [distributed-system](/questions/tagged/distributed-system) ML-pipeline processing monitor, than to "embed" progress-bar "inside"-ML-pipeline, it is devastatingly expensive, if hunting for indeed wasted nanoseconds of a professional ML-pipeline infrastructure. While it may seem as a good idea for prototyping, once a global search-space and the problem-scale goes into run-time ranges of a few **`[CPU*weeks]`**, even a few nanoseconds naively wasted per cycle stop to be a fun.

**4 ) XML-BEAUTIFIED MODEL COMPONENTS :**
I cannot speak in general, as I do not see any utility coming from "expensive" non-core XML-or-*-beautified model descriptions.

The last ~ 60 years of advanced HPC focused, low-latency crafted processing has never used a single non-core feature if striving for ultimate processing performance, which in **`O( R^n * I^m )`** scaled search-spaces, having `n ~ ( 3, 6+ ); m ~ ( 1, 4+ )`, simply do not have place.
Sorry for being direct and opened - hope you will enjoy these view ( Marketing may broadcast the very opposite, but facts matter ).